# Autofill the missing variable (input)

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, missing-data, autofill

Hi most supportive community in the world.
There is there input in my app. if you put only two of them you can easily calculate the other one. So i want to make it if you only put two of them, number there whichever this is, being calculated and the result being put in input place and be visible to user in real-time.completely automatic without needing to press any button from user. how do i do it? I'm using JavaScript.
Regards and thanks to everyone reading this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand is that you have 2 inputs and when the user fills both these inputs the result is calculated and shown to the user without the user having to do anything else.

So, for example, if the purpose was to show the sum if the user enters `3` in one input box and `2` in the second one, the result `5` is shown to the user. If you can confirm this, I'll share a code snippet with details of how you can achieve this in javascript. Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).